# Underline shows when using materal-ui InputBase component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui InputBase component to create a search bar and it shows an underline. However when I write the same code in another project there is no underline..
Any clues to what the problem might be?

Here is the code for the search bar

```js
import React from 'react';
import { IconButton, InputBase, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        padding: '2px 4px',
        display: 'flex'
        alignItems: 'center'
        width: 400
    },
    input: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
        flex: 1,
    },
    iconButton: {
        padding: 10
    }
}));

export default function SearchBar() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    
    return (
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <InputBase
                className{classes.input}
                placeholder='Search..'
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
           />
           <IconButton
               type='submit'
               className={classes.iconButton}
               aria-label='search'
           >
               <SearchIcon />
           </IconButton>
        </Paper>
    )
}
```

Comment: on stack overflow, if you were to ask any questions, please provide us with codes that you have tried. Without the codes, we are unable to help you.

Comment: I agree with @SomeoneSpecial, it can be from material-UI different versions, global styling, theming, etc...

Comment: you probably just have conflicting css rules, you need to open the code inspector of your browser to figure out what rules are applied and where from